# import multiple csv and use for a post request

Tags: python, csv, import, python-requests

i need this need:

- import more than one csv file
- put them in a list
- insert the data taken from the csv files into a json
- send post requests on an api

I developed the following script in python:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import csv

with open("p.csv", 'r') as P:
    csvreader1 = csv.reader(P)
    pe = list(csvreader1)

with open("c.csv", 'r') as c:
    csvreader2 = csv.reader(c)
    cS = list(csvreader2)

for i in range(5):
    headers = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    json_data = {
        "c": cS[i],
        "pe": pe[i],
        "markers": [
            {
                "name": "Sasa",
                "data": "2017-08-15",
                "perc": "80.95",
                "data": "2017-08-15"
            }
        ]
    }
    print(json_data)
    basic = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pwd')

    response = requests.post(
        'url',
        auth=basic,
        headers=headers,
        json=json_data,
    )
```

but the problem is that the data that is inserted into the json is inserted as ['pluto']
then doing some research I found the replace method, but the following error returns:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

how can i fix this?
how can i enter list data without "[" and "]"
I already tried:

```
pe = str(pe)
pe=pe.replace("[","")
pe=pe.replace("]","")
```

and too:

```
pe = [w.strip().split(']', '') for w in pe]
```

csv files are composed as follows:

```
YYYYY
BBBBB
EBBBB
RFFFF
DGGGG
FFFFF
...
```

Comment: `pe` seems to be a list of lists, and you want to flatten it. Try `pe = [inner[0] for inner in pe]`. If you have multiple columns in the CSV file, you may need to use `inner[j]`, where j is the column index.

Comment: @EmilioSilva this work thanks ! but can you explain the problem and the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are being printed as `['pluto']` because they are lists, and the string *representation* of a list includes brackets. The elements of the list are strings, and their representation includes the quotes.

You were treating the values as strings, but they only become strings when you `print()` them.

They are lists because CSVs, in general, can have multiple values per line. For instance, if you have a CSV containing:

```
AAA, BBB, CCC
DDD, EEE, FFF
```

Each line will be read as a list of strings:

```py
    L1 = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
    L2 = ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']
```

When you write `pe = list(csvreader1)`, you make a new list containing all those:

```py
pe = [
         ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
         ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF'],
     ]
```

This means that `pe[idx]` is a list.

In your specific case, the CSVs have a single column, so:

```
pe = [
         ['AAA'],
         ['BBB'],
         ['CCC'],
         ['DDD'],
         ['EEE'],
         ['FFF'],
     ]
```

The "traditional" way to flatten this is:

```py
pe_new = list()
for pe_item in pe:
    # pe_item is the list, e.g. ['AAAA']
    # pe_item[0] is the string, e.g. 'AAAA'
    pe_new.append(pe_item[0])
```

The list comprehension is a shorter way to write the same code:

```py
pe_new = [pe_item[0] for pe_item in pe]
```